# Getting repeated fields via inheritance with GetFields()

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a problem while working with `GetFields()` method while trying to get all the fields from a user defined class.

I have a parent class with, lets say two public fields, and another class that inherits from the parent and overrides one of the parent fields with the `new` keyword.

Problem comes when I use the `GetFields` method with the second class, because it's returning all the fields, including the overriden one. Is there something that I am doing wrong or a solution for only getting in this case the `GoodBye` field from the Parent class and the only one `Hello` field, the one from the inherited class?

This is a simple example of what I'm saying:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Hello = "sdfsafda";

        public string GoodBye = string.Empty;
    }


    public class Bar : Foo
    {
        public new string Hello = "jl";
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var a = new Bar();



        var derp = new List<string>();

        foreach (var fieldInfo in a.GetType().GetFields())
        {

            derp.Add(fieldInfo.Name);

        }

        Console.WriteLine(derp.Count);
        // writes 3 instead of 2

    }
```

About using Properties instead of Fields, I'm afraid I can't use them right now because of limitations that are not in my hand to solve in the project I'm working on.

Comment: Why you need refleection at all? Just out of interest?

Comment: Depending on using `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` you can decide to get all parent fields or none. If you want to filter them you have to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no pre-collected information about shadowed fields available. If you just need a simple workaround, you can first get the names of all fields without duplicates and then use `GetField(fieldName)` to only get the most derived field instance:

```
var type = a.GetType();
foreach (var field1 in type.GetFields().Select(x => x.Name).Distinct())
{
    var fieldInfo = type.GetField(field1);
    derp.Add(fieldInfo.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(fieldInfo.DeclaringType);
    Console.WriteLine(fieldInfo);
}
```

ofcourse, if you only need the field names like in your question code, instead of the `FieldInfo` object, you can stop after the `.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct()`.